# While running the script throws cannot find module 'dotenv'

Tags: puppeteer, cypress, dotenv

While loading the `.env` file to pass env values to the `getToken.js` script in the cypress root folder throws  Cannot find module 'dotenv'error. I have installed `npm install dotenv`. Could someone please advise what I am missing here ? `.env` file is available in cypress root folder.

Environment : Windows 10 >  git bash /command prompt

```
    const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
    require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'})
    
    const baseURL = process.env.CYPRESS_BASE_URL
    const testsUser = process.env.CYPRESS_TESTS_USERNAME
puppeteer
  .launch({ headless: true, chromeWebSecurity: false, args: ['--no-sandbox'] })
  .then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(`${baseURL}/login`);

    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.waitForSelector("input[name=username]");
    await page.type("input[name=username]", testsUser , {
      delay: 50
    });

    browser.close();
  });
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "cy:run": "cypress run",
    "get-token-main": "node getToken.js && mv tokenData.json cypress/fixtures",
    "cy:open-qa": "npm run get-token-main && cypress open"
```

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
Require stack:
- /e2e/getToken.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/e2e/getToken.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/e2e/getToken.js' ]
```

Comment: Anyone has faced similar problem?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should check if dotenv is installed, otherwise type in terminal:

```js
npm install --save dotenv
```

or [dotenv-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-extended)

```js
npm install --save dotenv-extended
```

Comment: I have already installed `dotenv`. The error disappeared after I had restarted my IDE.

Answer (score 8):

The reason to have that issue is that you have to add in your tsconfig.json under 'compilerOptions', the 'moduleResolution' value 'node'. With that, everything should work fine! :)
In other words:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",     // add this line.
   ...
  },
...
```

Comment: Why do you think it's a typescript project?

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same problem when I delete the package-lock.json file and create a new one. To fix this run the following cmd:

```
 npm install dotenv
```

Try to install again even if you have to installed dotenv.

Answer (score 3):

Just throwing out another answer here for those that might need it.

In my case, it was because the .env file wasn't in same folder as my entry point file.

My entry point was src/index.js, and my .env file was outside of src.  Once I moved .env to the same directory, I stopped having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Completely unrelated to the question, however I was running prisma and wanted to configure my env file location using the cli.

Adding `dotenv-cli` to `dev dependencies` worked for me:

```
npm install -g dotenv-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and in my case in order to deploy on https://www.cyclic.sh/ it looked like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha tests/unit/",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
    "start": "node src/index.ts"
},
```

I correct the feature

```
"start": "node src/index.ts"  to "start": "nodemon src/index.ts"
```

and the problem was gone!

Comment: what you did is switch from `node` which is the runtime environment to `nodemon` which automatically schedules jobs to be run in `node` if files change. this has absolutely nothing to do with `dotenv`

Answer (score -1):

You should set dotenv in your files correctly as follows:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```