# Dotenv not found after running npm start

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, npm-install

After running npm start, the error is

```
 Dotenv not found.
```

But the env file is in the root, check screenshot.

[Visual Studio - file structure and package json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2DCV.png)

My app is done in MERN stack and trying to run on development mode.

Please help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: the error is: 'Dotenv not found"

Comment: have you installed dotenv as a dependancy?

Comment: yes i have added it as a dependency

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61407393/while-running-the-script-throws-cannot-find-module-dotenv

Comment: Its strange, the env.development is there in the root but it seems to throw Dotenv not found

Comment: I've never seen an error like this in javascript. How do you use `dotenv` in your code?